# Can anyone give me an example of how to use Angular Agility

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use [Angular Agility](https://github.com/AngularAgility/AngularAgility) for form validation.  I'm trying to get a simple example working with the correct error messages and colours outlining the form element.  So far I'm not getting very far.  I've had a look at the demo examples but there's no clear code examples, unless I'm doing something drastically wrong.

Can anyone show me an example of how to use this properly?

For example how would I be able to get the following html to show the error message and the validation outline around the form element?

From the documentation?

```
<div ng-form="exampleForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <input type="number" aa-field-group="person.age" min="0" max="140" required>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plnkr shows how to validate the firstname, show the error message and show green/red outline round the form element:

http://plnkr.co/edit/V4vDiu?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="exampleModule">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="aa.formExtensions.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="exampleController" ng-form="exampleForm">

<div>
    <input type="text" required="" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="30"
           aa-auto-field="firstName" />
</div>

    <button aa-save-form="save()">Save</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the angular.js and angular-agility.js, here is a working sample

```
<!Doctype html>
<head>
 <link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AngularAgility/AngularAgility/master/simple_example/aa.formExtensionsOptional.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="angularAgilitySimpleExample" ng-controller="indexCtrl">
        <div ng-form="exampleForm">
            <input type="number" aa-field-group="person.age" min="0" max="140" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-agility.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('angularAgilitySimpleExample', ['aa.formExtensions', 'aa.notify']);
       </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Incase, you do not see the styling, please download the css from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AngularAgility/AngularAgility/master/simple_example/aa.formExtensionsOptional.css and use it locally

You can find the complete example from angular-agility team https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AngularAgility/AngularAgility/master/simple_example/index.html